# Using Sonatype Nexus docker proxy

Tags: java, docker, nginx, proxy, nexus

I have a Sonatype Nexus deployed under repository.company.com (it's behind an nginx proxy).

I created a docker registry and docker proxy and added them to one docker group "company-docker-group". The proxy is set to mirror https://registry-1.docker.io and also has the foreign layer caching option checked.

I have a http connector set for port 8092 but at this moment I do not have access to change the nginx configuration so that I can access that port directly. I noticed that there is an URL in the docker group defined as `https://repository.company.com/repository/company-docker-group/`

Am I able to access the group via this url? I am able to `docker login` into this url but then when I try
`docker pull repository.company.com/repository/company-docker-group/maven:3.6.2-jdk-8`
then I get this error:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for repository.company.com/repository/company-docker-group/maven:3.6.2-jdk-8 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Can I only access the image via `repository.company.com:8092/maven:3.6.2-jdk-8` or is there a way to use the docker group URL?

Comment: Docker registries must run on web context path "/", so trying to pull from "/repository/company-docker-group" isn't going to work.  See our docs for information on how to get the repository to appear on context path "/":  https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/SSL+and+Repository+Connector+Configuration

Answer (score 0):

[Sonatype documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/docker-registry/ssl-and-repository-connector-configuration) - on the subject - tells us that:

> **Docker relies on secure connections using SSL** to connect to the repositories. **You are** therefore **required to expose the repository** manager **to your client** tools **via HTTPS**

> **Interaction** of the **docker client with repositories requires specific ports** to be used. These can be configured in the repository configuration in the Repository Connectors section

> In order for this to work on your network, **you need to ensure** that the **chosen ports are available in your organization** and not used by some other application, and that no firewall or other network configuration prevents connectivity

Therefore, regarding your case, you must log in to your custom docker registry through the command `docker login https://repository.company.com:8092`

After successful login, imagine you want to save a custom image of `nginx`, named `mynginx`, into a `com/company/proxy` folder, within the company's private docker registry. In order to be able to push/pull images to/from your custom docker repository, you must:

1. Tag your image as `repository.company.com:8092/com/company/proxy/mynginx:1.0.0` through the command `docker tag mynginx:1.0.0 repository.company.com:8092/com/company/proxy/mynginx:1.0.0`.
2. Apply the following command in order to push your custom image to the company's private docker registry: `docker push repository.company.com:8092/com/company/proxy/mynginx:1.0.0`

By saving your custom image you can always pull it using: `docker pull repository.company.com:8092/com/company/proxy/mynginx:1.0.0`